# Different types of Cron Expression

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am a little confused about the Cron expression used in the unix system and the one Java Quartz is used.

The left-most entry of standard cron expression used by Unix represents "minute". But the cron expression used by Quartz uses the left most entry to represent "second":

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

I want to know how many versions of cron expression are currently being used?

What happens if I pass the standard version of cron into Quartz?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I can't believe there are only 2 people in the universe who've ever wondered about this.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how much versions of Cron expression exist but the most famous one is indeed the Unix one.

If you want to translate a Unix Cron expression to a Quartz Cron expression consider this.

Quartz format is :

```
(second, minute, hour, day_of_month, month, day_of_week, year)
```

Unix format is :

```
        (minute, hour, day_of_month, month, day_of_week, task)
```

So if you to translate a Unix cron into Quartz, you just have to add a value for the `second` and `year`.

If you want the same cron, you use 0 for `second` and `*` for `year`

Comment: At least some Unix implementations (currently looking at RHEL 7) exclude the "year" field. According to `man 5 crontab` on this server, "The 'sixth' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run."